# SSLError while trying to install pip for python3.4 on Raspbian-Stretch (Armv7l)

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, python-3

The issue is that I have a tensorflow .whl targeted towards python3.4 but by default on raspbian-stretch python3.5 is installed so I installed python3.4 python3.4-dev using apt-get. After that i downloaded get-pip.py and tried to build it with python3.4 but getting the error

`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3.4 get-pip.py 
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting pip
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping`

Awaiting community support, Thanks.

Comment: have you installed python3-openssl?

Comment: Puplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071378/how-to-make-ssl-work-in-pip3

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX yes i have tried to install python3-openssl but the problem i presume would be that the installation would proceed for python3.5 instead of python3.4

Comment: python3-openssl doesn't seem to be specifically for 3.5 or 3.4 ... just 3